# Give me some hints in computing the sum of series.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1} \right )\cdot 2^{-n}$$
As I think we should use integrating here or geometric series for $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1}$. But still I can't catch the idea.

Comment: Hint:  split the sum.  that is, do $\sum \frac 1{n2^n}$ and $\sum \frac 1{(n+1)2^n}$ separately.

Comment: @lulu, okay, and what to do next?

Comment: You already said.  Try integrating.  We know $\sum x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$ so $\sum \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\int \frac {dx}{1-x}$.  That more or less gives you one of the sums.

Comment: your partial sum containes the Lerch function

Comment: @IlyaTelefus differentiate $\frac{x^n}{n}$ w.r.t x and something familiar appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^{n}} = \bigg[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \bigg]_0^{\frac12} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{\frac12} x^{n-1}dx = \int_0^{\frac12} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n-1}dx = \int_0^{\frac12} \frac{dx}{1-x}= \log 2
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n}} = 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{(n+1)}}=2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^{n}} = 2(\log 2 -\frac12)
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1} \right )\cdot 2^{-n} = \log 8 -1
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

For $x\in (0,1) $,

$$S_1 (x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+....$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac {1}{1-x} $$
by integration

$\color {red}{x}+x^2/2+x^3/3+...= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^n}{n}$
$$=-\ln (1-x)+\ln (1-0) $$
thus

$S_2 (x)=x/2+x^2/3+...=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^n}{n+1}$

$$=(-\ln (1-x)-\color {red}{x})\frac {1}{x} $$

we find
$$S_1 (1/2)+S_2 (1/2)=$$
$$\ln (2)+2 (\ln (2 )-1/2)=3\ln(2)-1$$

Comment: why don't you have$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ here $\color {red}{x}+x^2/2+x^3/3+...= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^n}{n}$

Comment: @IlyaTelefus I am waiting for your remark.

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ is known to be

$$\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n.$$

With $x=\dfrac12$ and with a shift of the indexes, you can recognize that the given expression is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}n-1=-\log\left(1-\frac12\right)-2\log\left(1-\frac12\right)-1=3\log2-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n (n+\alpha)}$ is absolutely convergent for any $\alpha>-1$, hence
$$ S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n2^n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)2^n}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n2^n}+2\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n2^n}=T+2\left(T-\frac{1}{2}\right)\tag{1} $$
and:
$$ S = 3T-1 = -1-3\left.\log\left(1-x\right)\right|_{x=\frac{1}{2}}= \color{red}{3\log 2-1}\tag{2}$$
by the Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dz}{1+z}=\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n z^n\,dz$.